# Laravel with MongoDB only or MongoDB + MySQL for authentication?

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5

I'm building a Laravel app. My data requires me to have a mongoDB database, so I'm building the app with Laravel + MongoDB. Works well so far, but when condidering user authentication, I'm not sure Mongo is the best option, so I'm divided between using Mongo or having an extra Mysql database just for user auth.

Using only Mongo keeps the app simpler(just one db adapter), but it seems that saving users as json documents a bit of bad design (sorry, I come from a SQL background). Not only that, but as my data increases, seems that query calls for users would take longer and longer to return.

On the other hand, MySQL would add an extra db adapter to the app, extra server memory load to keep mysql running, and one more endpoint that can fail or crash on the long run, but I have a feeling that it would retrieve users and authenticate them faster.

Are there any big drawbacks on having my user data stored in MongoDB instead of Mysql or any great benefits in using MySQL instead of Mongo to store users?

Comment: Dragging a MySQL database in just so you can use it for authentication is a bad idea. If anything if you ever go on cloud services you're just increasing your costs for no real benefit.

Comment: Call me mad but if you do not expect 1,000,000,000 users go with sqlite (if on SSD, which you most likely will be) if you really need SQL. (do not take me sirius).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm building a Laravel app. My data requires me to have a mongoDB
>   database, so I'm building the app with Laravel + MongoDB. Works well
>   so far, but when condidering user authentication, I'm not sure Mongo
>   is the best option, so I'm divided between using Mongo or having an
>   extra Mysql database just for user auth.

Go for it!
Do not afraid using MongoDB as authentication storage.
There's no compelling reasons using MySQL for authentication only as there is MongoDB for everything else.

> ...but it seems that saving users as json documents a bit of bad
>   design (sorry, I come from a SQL background). Not only that, but as my
>   data increases, seems that query calls for users would take longer and
>   longer to return.

That's just a misconception!
At most, querying a **MongoDB** is too fast. You shouldn't worry on that for now.

> On the other hand, **MySQL** would add an extra db adapter to the app,
>   extra server memory load to keep mysql running, and one more endpoint
>   that can fail or crash on the long run...

Fair enough!
For my experience is a pain in the ass maintaining MySQL (in the current context) just for authentication:
2 servers, 2 backups, 2 restores, 2 deployments, extra configuration and more headaches...

Even though Moloquent (I suppose the application has `jenssegers/laravel-mongodb package`, at best...) supports hybrid relations
is much easier having just one database.

### Final words

Well, before to decide to using MongoDB for authentication you ought to modify User class file, switching/refering to proper namespaces (mongo).
A little bit of work but it worth!
In the past, I've imported all users from MySQL for MongoDB and I'm pretty satisfied with.